# How can I preview pdf in adobe reader or other editor instead of Yap using lyx

Tags: lyx, pdf, adobe, sumatrapdf

I recently installed lyx on a new computer. And it seems that I can't preview the pdf in adobe reader or sumatra. The yap software is invoked to preview the pdf. I tried to add the adobe path, change the preview to AcroRD32 or Summatra. I even re-installed lyx. Nothing works so far. This is really bothering me since I need to adjust the look of the paper. With yap, I can't really see how the paper looks like now.

Comment: This message was also sent to lyx-users mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=CAGbF0QPABjfvjoDV61Wj5amiWj7DhKX4p8yCSw%3DD7o27-rjO%3Dg%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

I only have lyx 2.0.8 in Linux, without Sumatra nor Acroread, but I hope this guide help:

> <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences ...</kbd> >
>
> <kbd>Ouput</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > **Foward search** >
>
> <kbd>PDF command</kbd> > `SumatraPDF -reuse-instance $$o -forward-search $$t $$n`
>
> <kbd>File handling</kbd> > <kbd>File formats</kbd> >
>
> <kbd>Format:</kbd>  > `PDF (pdflatex)`  (for example)
>
> <kbd>Viewer:</kbd>  > `Custom` >  `SumatraPDF` (I guess...)
>
> <kbd>Apply</kbd>